# Error reading from SCI port. No data. Turtlebot disconnects when set Full Mode

Tags: ros, kinect, turtlebot, gmapping-demo, icreate

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, there,

I have recently upgraded to Fuerte on Ubuntu 12.04. I tried to build SLAM map by following http://www.ros.org/wiki/turtlebot_navigation/Tutorials/Build%20a%20map%20with%20SLAM tutorial, but after I execute `roslaunch turtlebot_navigation gmapping_demo.launch` I receive error - "Failed to contact device with error: [Error reading from SCI port. No data.]. Please check that the Create is powered on and that the connector is plugged into the Create."

```
turtlebot@turtlebot-1215N:~$ sudo service turtlebot start
turtlebot start/running, process 4564
turtlebot@turtlebot-1215N:~$ roslaunch turtlebot_navigation gmapping_demo.launch
... logging to /home/turtlebot/.ros/log/0c768eee-c921-11e1-8666-485d60f51088/roslaunch-turtlebot-1215N-5175.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://192.168.1.6:41858/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /kinect_laser/max_height
 * /kinect_laser/min_height
 * /kinect_laser/output_frame_id
 * /kinect_laser_narrow/max_height
 * /kinect_laser_narrow/min_height
 * /kinect_laser_narrow/output_frame_id
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/acc_lim_th
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/acc_lim_x
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/acc_lim_y
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/dwa
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/goal_distance_bias
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/heading_lookahead
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/holonomic_robot
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/max_rotational_vel
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/max_vel_x
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/min_in_place_rotational_vel
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/min_vel_x
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/oscillation_reset_dist
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/path_distance_bias
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/sim_time
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/vtheta_samples
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/vx_samples
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/xy_goal_tolerance
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/yaw_goal_tolerance
 * /move_base/controller_frequency
 * /move_base/global_costmap/footprint
 * /move_base/global_costmap/footprint_padding
 * /move_base/global_costmap/global_frame
 * /move_base/global_costmap/inflation_radius
 * /move_base/global_costmap/observation_sources
 * /move_base/global_costmap/obstacle_range
 * /move_base/global_costmap/publish_frequency
 * /move_base/global_costmap/raytrace_range
 * /move_base/global_costmap/robot_base_frame
 * /move_base/global_costmap/scan/clearing
 * /move_base/global_costmap/scan/data_type
 * /move_base/global_costmap/scan/marking
 * /move_base/global_costmap/scan/topic
 * /move_base/global_costmap/static_map
 * /move_base/global_costmap/transform_tolerance
 * /move_base/global_costmap/update_frequency
 * /move_base/local_costmap/footprint
 * /move_base/local_costmap/footprint_padding
 * /move_base/local_costmap/global_frame
 * /move_base/local_costmap/height
 * /move_base/local_costmap/inflation_radius
 * /move_base/local_costmap/observation_sources
 * /move_base/local_costmap/obstacle_range
 * /move_base/local_costmap/publish_frequency
 * /move_base/local_costmap/raytrace_range
 * /move_base/local_costmap/resolution
 * /move_base/local_costmap/robot_base_frame
 * /move_base/local_costmap/rolling_window
 * /move_base/local_costmap/scan/clearing
 * /move_base/local_costmap/scan/data_type
 * /move_base/local_costmap/scan/marking
 * /move_base/local_costmap/scan/topic
 * /move_base/local_costmap/static_map
 * /move_base/local_costmap/transform_tolerance
 * /move_base/local_costmap/update_frequency
 * /move_base/local_costmap/width
 * /openni_launch/debayering
 * /openni_launch/depth_frame_id
 * /openni_launch/depth_mode
 * /openni_launch/depth_registration
 * /openni_launch/depth_time_offset
 * /openni_launch/image_mode
 * /openni_launch/image_time_offset
 * /openni_launch/rgb_frame_id
 * /pointcloud_throttle/max_rate
 * /rosdistro
 * /rosversion
 * /slam_gmapping/angularUpdate
 * /slam_gmapping/astep
 * /slam_gmapping/delta
 * /slam_gmapping/iterations
 * /slam_gmapping/kernelSize
 * /slam_gmapping/lasamplerange
 * /slam_gmapping/lasamplestep
 * /slam_gmapping/linearUpdate
 * /slam_gmapping/llsamplerange
 * /slam_gmapping/llsamplestep
 * /slam_gmapping/lsigma
 * /slam_gmapping/lskip
 * /slam_gmapping/lstep
 * /slam_gmapping/map_update_interval
 * /slam_gmapping/maxUrange
 * /slam_gmapping/odom_frame
 * /slam_gmapping/ogain
 * /slam_gmapping/particles
 * /slam_gmapping/resampleThreshold
 * /slam_gmapping/sigma
 * /slam_gmapping/srr
 * /slam_gmapping/srt
 * /slam_gmapping/str
 * /slam_gmapping/stt
 * /slam_gmapping/temporalUpdate
 * /slam_gmapping/xmax
 * /slam_gmapping/xmin
 * /slam_gmapping/ymax
 * /slam_gmapping/ymin

NODES
  /
    kinect_breaker_enabler (turtlebot_node/kinect_breaker_enabler.py)
    kinect_laser (nodelet/nodelet)
    kinect_laser_narrow (nodelet/nodelet)
    move_base (move_base/move_base)
    openni_launch (nodelet/nodelet)
    openni_manager (nodelet/nodelet)
    pointcloud_throttle (nodelet/nodelet)
    slam_gmapping (gmapping/slam_gmapping)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.168.1.6:11311

core service [/rosout] found
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[kinect_breaker_enabler-1]: started with pid [5204]
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[openni_manager-2]: started with pid [5205]
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[openni_launch-3]: started with pid [5212]
[ INFO] [1341768064.009254575]: Initializing nodelet with 4 worker threads.
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[pointcloud_throttle-4]: started with pid [5257]
[ INFO] [1341768064.225824642]: [/openni_launch] No devices connected.... waiting for devices to be connected
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[kinect_laser-5]: started with pid [5272]
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[kinect_laser_narrow-6]: started with pid [5289]
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[slam_gmapping-7]: started with pid [5306]
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[move_base-8]: started with pid [5353]
[ INFO] [1341768065.255244721]: [/openni_launch] No devices connected.... waiting for devices to be connected
[ INFO] [1341768065.529859405]: Subscribed to Topics: scan
[ INFO] [1341768065.572297783]: Requesting the map...

[ INFO] [1341768065.577921498]: Still waiting on map...

[ INFO] [1341768066.276262791]: [/openni_launch] No devices connected.... waiting for devices to be connected
[ INFO] [1341768066.578017762]: Still waiting on map...

[kinect_breaker_enabler-1] process has finished cleanly
log file: /home/turtlebot/.ros/log/0c768eee-c921-11e1-8666-485d60f51088/kinect_breaker_enabler-1*.log
[ INFO] [1341768067.298705975]: [/openni_launch] No devices connected.... waiting for devices to be connected
[ INFO] [1341768067.577962126]: Still waiting on map...

[ INFO] [1341768068.322282553]: [/openni_launch] No devices connected.... waiting for devices to be connected
[ INFO] [1341768068.578022351]: Still waiting on map...

[ INFO] [1341768069.577965591]: Still waiting on map...

[ INFO] [1341768070.577958843]: Still waiting on map...

[ INFO] [1341768071.078922315]: [/openni_launch] Number devices connected: 1
[ INFO] [1341768071.079242958]: [/openni_launch] 1. device on bus 001:39 is a Xbox NUI Camera (2ae) from Microsoft (45e) with serial id 'B00367206887043B'
[ WARN] [1341768071.082777081]: [/openni_launch] device_id is not set! Using first device.
[ INFO] [1341768071.179295315]: [/openni_launch] Opened 'Xbox NUI Camera' on bus 1:39 with serial number 'B00367206887043B'
[ INFO] [1341768071.221746341]: rgb_frame_id = 'camera_rgb_optical_frame' 
[ INFO] [1341768071.229172662]: depth_frame_id = 'camera_depth_optical_frame' 
[ INFO] [1341768071.577994695]: Still waiting on map...

[ INFO] [1341768072.577971674]: Still waiting on map...

 -maxUrange 16 -maxUrange 9.99 -sigma     0.05 -kernelSize 1 -lstep 0.05 -lobsGain 3 -astep 0.05
 -srr 0.01 -srt 0.02 -str 0.01 -stt 0.02
 -linearUpdate 0.5 -angularUpdate 0.436 -resampleThreshold 0.5
 -xmin -1 -xmax 1 -ymin -1 -ymax 1 -delta 0.05 -particles 80
[ INFO] [1341768073.100087569]: Initialization complete
update frame 0
update ld=0 ad=0
Laser Pose= 0 0 0
m_count 0
Registering First Scan
[ INFO] [1341768073.578165576]: Still waiting on map...

[ INFO] [1341768074.591897075]: Received a 32 X 32 map at 0.050000 m/pix

[ WARN] [1341768074.806385721]: Costmap2DROS transform timeout. Current time: 1341768074.8062, global_pose stamp: 1341768074.0065, tolerance: 0.5000
[ INFO] [1341768075.160692480]: MAP SIZE: 32, 32
[ INFO] [1341768075.181478240]: Subscribed to Topics: scan
[ INFO] [1341768075.803084198]: Sim period is set to 0.20
[ WARN] [1341768076.473023023]: Costmap2DROS transform timeout. Current time: 1341768076.4729, global_pose stamp: 1341768074.0065, tolerance: 0.5000
[ WARN] [1341768076.872924590]: Could not get robot pose, cancelling reconfiguration
[ WARN] [1341768077.473032476]: Costmap2DROS transform timeout. Current time: 1341768077.4729, global_pose stamp: 1341768074.0065, tolerance: 0.5000
[ WARN] [1341768077.874107868]: Could not get robot pose, cancelling reconfiguration
[ WARN] [1341768078.473300976]: Costmap2DROS transform timeout. Current time: 1341768078.4731, global_pose stamp: 1341768074.0065, tolerance: 0.5000
[ WARN] [1341768078.973711024]: Could not get robot pose, cancelling reconfiguration
[ WARN] [1341768079.473889132]: Costmap2DROS transform timeout. Current time: 1341768079.4738, global_pose stamp: 1341768074.0065, tolerance: 0.5000
[ WARN] [1341768079.973774740]: Could not get robot pose, cancelling reconfiguration
[ WARN] [1341768080.474282223]: Costmap2DROS transform timeout. Current time: 1341768080.4741, global_pose stamp: 1341768074.0065, tolerance: 0.5000
[ WARN] [1341768080.973871987]: Could not get robot pose, cancelling reconfiguration
[ WARN] [1341768081.474447913]: Costmap2DROS transform timeout. Current time: 1341768081.4743, global_pose stamp: 1341768074.0065, tolerance: 0.5000
[ WARN] [1341768081.973958267]: Could not get robot pose, cancelling reconfiguration
[ WARN] [1341768082.574226441]: Costmap2DROS transform timeout. Current time: 1341768082.5740, global_pose stamp: 1341768074.0065, tolerance: 0.5000
[ WARN] [1341768083.073476986]: Could not get robot pose, cancelling reconfiguration
[ WARN] [1341768083.574545923]: Costmap2DROS transform timeout. Current time: 1341768083.5744, global_pose stamp: 1341768074.0065, tolerance: 0.5000
[ERROR] [1341768083.774149730]: Extrapolation Error looking up robot pose: Unable to lookup transform, cache is empty, when looking up transform from frame [/base_link] to frame [/map]

[ WARN] [1341768084.074333263]: Could not get robot pose, cancelling reconfiguration
[ERROR] [1341768084.774230352]: Extrapolation Error looking up robot pose: Unable to lookup transform, cache is empty, when looking up transform from frame [/base_link] to frame [/map]

[ WARN] [1341768085.174787510]: Could not get robot pose, cancelling reconfiguration
[ERROR] [1341768085.806383046]: Extrapolation Error looking up robot pose: Unable to lookup transform, cache is empty, when looking up transform from frame [/base_link] to frame [/map]

[ WARN] [1341768086.273697846]: Could not get robot pose, cancelling reconfiguration
[ERROR] [1341768086.806457177]: Extrapolation Error looking up robot pose: Unable to lookup transform, cache is empty, when looking up transform from frame [/base_link] to frame [/map]

[ WARN] [1341768087.273752552]: Could not get robot pose, cancelling reconfiguration
[ERROR] [1341768087.819976917]: Extrapolation Error looking up robot pose: Lookup would require extrapolation into the past.  Requested time 1341768074.006515026 but the earliest data is at time 1341768077.837952710, when looking up transform from frame [/base_link] to frame [/odom]

[ WARN] [1341768088.274151997]: Could not get robot pose, cancelling reconfiguration
```

...

Basically, after I run roslaunch turtlebot_navigation gmapping_demo.launch connection with iCreate and power board with gyro brakes and I can't receive current robot position. Turtlebot Dashboard shows that mode is set as full; Kinect powered; and error "msg: Failed to contact device with error: [Error reading from SCI port. No data.]. Please check that the Create is powered on and that the connector is plugged into the Create."

If I turn on iCreate by pressing power button on it, I have turtlebot back with "Mode: safe". As soon as I switch to Full mode, within 15 seconds iCreate turns off.

Battery is fully charged. Not sure what is going on and how I can fix it. Please, help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38199/error-reading-from-sci-port.-no-data.-turtlebot-disconnects-when-set-full-mode/) by [Roman Burdakov](https://answers.ros.org/users/1201/roman-burdakov/) on ROS Answers with karma: 131 on 2012-07-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

if you have a DMM (multimeter) please measure the voltage across the battery to make sure that it is fully charged.

---

Originally posted by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) with karma: 8372 on 2012-07-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2014-05-05**:
Similar: http://answers.ros.org/question/62893/turtlebot-bringup-error-robot-not-connected/